# Facebook account kit(API) loginCallback doesn't execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, api

I am currently implementing the facebook account kit for my Rails application. I just use the smslogin function, no email. I got the verification code, enter it to the popup window, it verifies successfully. However, the function loginCallback doesn't execute after that. Actually, there are a couple of times it is executed. I am really frustrated here because I don't now what is going with the code, it is totally out of my control. It would be helpful if somebody can give some hints or tips here.
This is the code for my login page:

**fb_account_kit.htm.haml**:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{:content => "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}/
    %title Passwordless Authentication: Facebook Account Kit
    / Include the Account Kit SDK
    %script{:src => "https://sdk.accountkit.com/vi_VN/sdk.js"}
  %body
    .ui.container
      = form_tag('https://www.accountkit.com/v1.0/basic/dialog/sms_login/', method: :get, class: 'ui form') do
        = hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token
        .field
          = text_field_tag 'country_code', '+84', {class: 'ui input'}
        .field
          = text_field_tag 'phone_number', nil, {placeholder: 'phone number', class: 'ui input'}
        .field
          = button_tag 'Login via SMS', {onclick: 'javascript:smsLogin()', class: 'ui primary button'}

      -#Login success form
      = form_tag('/login_success', method: :post, class: 'ui form', id: 'login_success') do
        = hidden_field_tag 'code'
        = hidden_field_tag 'csrf'

:javascript
  // initialize Account Kit with CSRF protection
  AccountKit_OnInteractive = function(){
    AccountKit.init(
      {
        debug: true,
        appId: "myapp_id_goes_here",
        state: $('#authenticity_token').val(),
        version: "v1.0",
        fbAppEventsEnabled: true
      }
    );
  };

  // login callback
  function loginCallback(response) {
    alert('inside loginCallback NOW!!!');
    alert('response object: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
    if (response.status === "PARTIALLY_AUTHENTICATED") {
      document.getElementById("code").value = response.code;
      document.getElementById("csrf").value = response.state;
      console.log('login_success form is gonna be submitted!!!');
      document.getElementById("login_success").submit();
    }
    else if (response.status === "NOT_AUTHENTICATED") {
      alert('authentication failed')
    }
    else if (response.status === "BAD_PARAMS") {
      alert('bad parameters')
    }
  }

  // phone form submission handler
  function smsLogin() {
    var countryCode = document.getElementById("country_code").value;
    var phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phone_number").value;
    AccountKit.login(
      'PHONE',
      {countryCode: countryCode, phoneNumber: phoneNumber},
      loginCallback
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the response by client side Javascript callback, then you don't have to add `redirect` option.
The `redirect` option just for server handling the login callback.

Hence, this configuration should make your example work

```
  // initialize Account Kit with CSRF protection
  AccountKit_OnInteractive = function(){
    AccountKit.init(
      {
        debug: true,
        appId: "myapp_id_goes_here",
        state: $('#authenticity_token').val(),
        version: "v1.0",
        fbAppEventsEnabled: true
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: I've just updated my question. The loginCallback function isn't still executed after I remove the redirect option.